# Is there a nontrivial topological group that's isomorphic to its fundamental group?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, fundamental-groups

All I know is that the topological group has to be Abelian. I have no idea how to prove or disprove this statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is answered here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43002/fundamental-groups-of-topological-groups

Answer (score 10):

An answer to this can be found on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43002/fundamental-groups-of-topological-groups).

The answer on MathOverflow gives an example of a topological group $G$ which is isomorphic to its own fundamental group (as an abstract group). The example is a product of infinitely many $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$'s, or rather a group structure associated to $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ (or, easier to see, its universal cover $S^\infty$). The underlying group is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$.

(Note: This question is lying pretty high up the unanswered group theory question list, so I have added in this community wiki answer to get it off of the list.)